# Importing google.colab in VM Engine Doesn't Let me Run Jupyter Notebook in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a script on Google Colab that needs a lot of memory usage, so I tried linking it to a VM engine on Google cloud. According to this [documentation](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html#:%7E:text=In%20Colaboratory%2C%20click%20the%20%22Connect,connected%20to%20your%20local%20runtime), you create the instance, run it, authenticate the jupyter notebook server, and connect the link to the local runtime. However, because I am using a local runtime to run everything, I have to import certain libraries. I was able to import tensorflow and matplot without any trouble and was able to connect to the server, but when I imported google.colab, it's not working. I've tested this thrice with different vm-instances, and every time it seems to be the case. Is there a way to fix this issue? Or if not, another way to access the datasets I need without using google colab? (code is below)

Thanks in advance

```
import pathlib
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
data_dir_ = "gdrive/My Drive/training"
data_dir_training = pathlib.Path(data_dir_training)
```

This is also how my notebook looks in Google Colab when I try running the code without importing google.colab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Pip installing google colab causes outdated libraries, so you have to pip upgrade it as well.